# CursorColumn isn't a continuous line anymore when wordwrap is on

Tags: highlight

Screen capture says it all:
[image]

Normally, the vertical highlighting is continuous, but because I have long lines word-wrapping around, only one character gets highlighted. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

No, this is the way the CursorColumn works.

Comment: ... And that's because the characters above and below the highlighted ones in the wrapped lines correspond to other columns.  Doing it any other way would be misleading.